# How can I choose the values of comparator resistors?

Tags: operational-amplifier, circuit-design, temperature, comparator, thermostat

I have a circuit that I use as a thermostat:

[image: My circuit]

My comparator is an [LM393](https://www.onsemi.com/pdf/datasheet/lm393-d.pdf).

I calculated the reference voltage and the R3/R4 ratio using the hysteresis calculation tool on this site: [calculator](https://www.daycounter.com/Calculators/Comparator-Hysteresis-Calculator.phtml)

So I found that the R2/R1 ratio = 15. Vref should be 0.83 V, so the R3/R4 ratio should be 5.

But what should the resistor values be?

Example: for R2/R1 = 15 => 75 kΩ, 5 kΩ or 600 kΩ, 40 kΩ or 15 kΩ, 1 kΩ or other values?

For R3/R4 = 5  => 80 kΩ, 16 kΩ or 300 kΩ, 60 kΩ or 10 kΩ, 2 kΩ or other values?

1. I have calculated the resistor ratios, but I don't know by what criteria I should choose the resistor values.
2. My NTC is 50 kΩ @ 25C, I have connected a 50 kΩ series resistor to the NTC. Maybe I should reconsider my resistor size choices here (as 10 kΩ NTC, 10 kΩ resistor or 100 kΩ NTC, 100 kΩ resistor)?

Comment: Are saying you couldn't find example circuits with formula on the Internet? There's a large amount of existing text already written on this in great detail, going back decades. Did you search the Internet or search this website for previous questions?

Comment: R3 & R4 form a voltage divider.  Determine your Vref, pick one resistor and calculate the other.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the voltage divider on the left to work as a voltage divider, then you have to ensure that the current flowing from out from the "middle" of the voltage divider is negligible compared to the current passing through the voltage divider.
More practicaly, that means that the sum of the resistors r=R1+R2 has to be FAR bigger than the resistors of the voltage divider.
If you don't respect that rule, Vin will shift from the "theoretical" value (a voltage divider is valid only if the same current flows through both resistors).

EDIT : for the question about the 5MOhm impedance :
I looked at the datasheet from ST (no idea from which manufacturer you take your LM393, so it might change a bit), where I haven't found directly an input impedance specification.
However, they give an input biais current Ib (20nA typ, 250nA max at 25°C, 400nA max accros whole temperature range).
So if that current flows through a resistor R, it gives you a voltage error of dU=Ib*R.
So depending which value you use, it is between 5Mhoms*20nA= 0.1V to 5Mohms*400nA =2V.
So if you want to build a single unit, you can hope to have a typical current, and if those 0.1V diference are OK for you (that depends of how many degrees it corresponds in the ntc), then you might try it.
If you are planning to produce many such circuit, you will probably have some circuits close to the "max", and then you are in trouble.

So I would say that idealy, the sum of R1+R2 should be at least 100 times the value of the voltage divider, so at least 100*50k = 5 megaohms

For R3 and R4, I would go for the same order of magnitude as R1 and R2 (I'm not sure for comparators, but I remember right, some OpAmps work best if the impedances are similar on both entrances, so it might me the same for comparators, and anyway it can't harm).

A last point is that some devices don't work well with input signals having high iresistance (5 Mohms is quite high). You should check it in the datasheet.
If your comparator don't likes 5MOhms input resistance, then going to 10k ntc,10k resistor or even lower is a good solution (so you can reduce R1 and R2). Basicaly, the lower your resistors the better, excepted if you care about power consumption.

Another solution to get rid of all those question would be to add an op-amp as follower between the voltage divider and the hysteresis circuit : this way, you garantee that no current goes out of the voltage divider, so you are totaly free of the values of your resistors (I would then recommend resistors in the 10k range)

So if you still can reduce all you resistors by a factor of 20 or more, then you are safe. If not, it's up to you if you want to try it or simply add an OpAmp

Comment: Thanks for informations.I understood most of what you said.But I couldn't find in the datasheet whether the comparator likes 5M ohms impedance.Can you help me?

Comment: One more question.Did you multiply the voltage divider resistor by 100 or did you multiply the ntc value by 100?

Comment: For the 1st question, I answered editing my post.
for the 2nd question : it's just orders of magnitudes, so it doesn't really matters. If the values were very diferent, then use the biggest of both (or multiply the sum by 50)

Comment: Please add a simulation or analysis with values that you recommend to improve this answer.